# How to Pass List of data from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have List like below in .cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About","Home")) 
{ 
<div id="Test">
<table id="DeptIds">
@for (int i = 0; i <= @Model.Count()-1;i++ )
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].DeptId)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x[i].DeptName)

    </td>
</tr>
 }


</table>

<input type="button" value="HitMe" onclick="Save()" />
</div>
}
<script>
function Save()
 {

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("About")',           
        data: $("#Test").serialize(),  
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('.tampil_vr').text(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The Save function will do the ajax method and serialize all the data and pass to controller.

Controller Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About(List<Dept> obj)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }
```

When i executed obj is null but if i change the  type="Submit" in obj i am getting the List data. So how to fill obj in ajax call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to serialize **form** not div

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("About","Home",FormMethod.Post,new {id="frm_Test"})) 
{ 
.....

...

}
```

In script provide Id of form to serialize

```
<script>
function Save()
 {

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("About")',           
        data: $("#frm_Test").serialize(),  
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $('.tampil_vr').text(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```